# Cannot perform queries

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a project, dataset and then a table, defining schema.  My data is imported via .csv and is about 500,000 rows by 43 columns.

Every query I run errors out with "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."  Even a simple query like:

SELECT cloudCover FROM [mydata_id] LIMIT 1000

What's the best way to troubleshoot this problem.

Specific job info for above query:
Job ID: bigqry-01:job_LsDLSN8sZ31NHYQ23O9bBmG-Mw8
Start Time: Dec 27, 2015, 4:35:25 PM
End Time: Dec 27, 2015, 4:35:25 PM
Destination Table: bigqry-01:_28fb568727f6622afd66aaf2534b44fc473d57d8.anonev_qqz4LTIXIyumxKokvJpoC7MqBTE

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're querying a [federated table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources). For importing the data into BigQuery you can look at [loading data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery).

I looked it up and your job actually failed because it cannot find the input file. Please double check that the URI you specified for the federated table is correct. We should expose this as user error instead of internal error. I created a bug to track it.